# Nginx to squid with rewrite url to different domain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, return, proxypass

I would like to ask you help me configure Nginx for specific location proxie to different domain  via squid server.

ie: http://example.com/picture.png -> squid -> https://diffentlocation.com/picture.png

I have tried use directives: proxy_pass and return

```
location /picture.png {
      proxy_pass http://<company squid server>:<port of squid>;
      return 301 https://diffentlocation.com/picture.png/;

}
```

Return is working fine but I don't see any request in squid logs.
So it don't work as expected. It mean if anybody ask for "picture" it should be rewrite to the different location and go through our squid servers.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: return 301 means redirect to there, not proxy pass. 

comment that return 301 and it should try to proxy_pass there.

Comment: yes you are right but if I will comment "return" request will NOT changed. I need rewrite/return to differentlocation.com and through proxy connect to the differentlocation. It is security reason. Servers are not directly opened  (firewall) to the differentlocation.com only via proxy (squid)